# how to make program in python to convert Romanize English to Devanagari Nepali?

Tags: python

I have wrote this code but now I have no idea what should I write to make this acomplish.

I want to make Romanize English to Devanagari Nepali converter program in python.
The program should convert like the example below.

"ke gardai chhau?" into "के गर्दै छौ?"

I have wrote this code and now I have no idea what should write to make it work.
Give me the basic principle and sample code how it works and what to write

```
# Romanaizer.py
# version 1.0
key_chars={
"a":"अ",
"aa":"आ",
"i":"इ",
"ii":"ई",
"u":"उ",
"U":"ऊ",
"e":"ए",
"ai":"ऐ",
"o":"ओ",
"au":"औ",
"am":"अं,
#"aa":,
"ka":'क',
"kha":'ख',
"ga":'ग',
"gha":'घ',
"nga":'ङ',
"cha":'च',
"chha":'छ',
"ja":'ज',
"jha":'झ',
"yna":'ञ',
"Ta":'ट',
"Tha":'ठ',
"Da":'ड',
"Dha":'ढ',
"Na":'ण',
"ta":'त',
"tha":'थ',
"da":'द',
"dha":'ध',
"na":'न',
"pa":'प',
"pha":'फ',
"ba":'ब',
"bha":'भ',
"ma":'म',
"ya":'य',
"ra":'र',
"la":'ल',
"va":'व',
"sa":'स',
"Sa":'श',
"sha":'ष',
"ha":'ह',
"kshya":'क्ष',
"tra":'त्र',
"gya":‌‍‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌'ज्ञ',
}
```

Comment: Possible next step: write code that converts a single syllable.

Comment: Add code that you have tried to make it work, so someone can guide you on that.

Comment: You will need to build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a similar structure and then check your input against it

Comment: You'll get better responses if you ask about small bits of the program that you're stuck on rather than asking the community to solve your entire problem